# Execute subscribe method only once at the time in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, rx-swift

I have a PublishObject object, which is feed by coming data (approximately
16 times per second). When objects coming so quickly, that can be a situation, when one is still processing, but the new one is ready to use. Is it a way to block executing another processing, when the earlier doesn't end his job?

Comment: "It doesn't matter on which thread they produce elements, but if they generate one element and send it to the observer observer.on(.next(nextElement)), they can't send next element until observer.on method has finished execution." https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md#implicit-observable-guarantees

Comment: It seems like your `PublishObject` has violated one of the requirements of an `Observable`

Comment: Indeed, you are correct, my PublishObject breaking one of the requirements, because I broke multithreading working on this object. Thanks for pointing this to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is called backpressure, and there are different strategies to handle it.

RxJava has *.onBackpressureBuffer()* operator, but RxSwift does not support it yet.

Perhaps you can copy Java implementation of it.